# Windows install docker from binary and set docker environemt variable

Tags: windows, ssh, docker, environment-variables, docker-for-windows

I have to install docker on Windows from binary.
I downloaded them and installed them as described in the [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/binaries/#install-server-and-client-binaries-on-windows).
I can run `docker ps` in the folder I installed docker at.

Outside of this folder I can only run command with the complete path to the `docker.exe` as `docker` as a command won't work.

I tried to use `set docker <path-to-docker.exe>` and `setx docker <path-to-docker.exe>` but it did not work.

I am using windows server via ssh as `remote` user.
I want to be able to use `docker ps` even after a reboot.
How can I achive this?

Comment: Did you reboot your machine?

Comment: Yes, i did. After reconnecting via ssh I could not use `docker ps`